# I leave my raspberry with VPN connection on, and after several hours, I connect to it but has no internet connection. How to troubleshoot/diagnose?

Tags: shell-script, networking, vpn

I connect my raspberry to VPN, and I leave it there for hours. When I check it connecting through SSH or VNC, I realize that it has not internet connection. If I reboot and then connect to VPN again it works again.

My question is: how to diagnose the problem? how to troubleshoot? Is there some log file or systemctl log that I can look into to find what cause the issue?

I want to automate that *if the Pi is not connected to the internet then it reboots*. I want to do that in a "clean" way via some `.target` file or `udev` rule.

Comment: the cleanest way would be to identify why it's losing internet connection (is it losing the VPN connection?) check the various log files in /var/log for a start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need to reboot.  Restarting the VPN connection when the rpi detects the outage should be good enough (unless it's a hardware fault).

As for detecting the outage, is there some host or IP address that you **know** you should be able to reach when the VPN is up but not when the VPN is down?  If so, set up a cron jobs that tries to `fping` that host.  If it responds then all is OK.  If not, restart the VPN.

Otherwise, if the VPN outage is noted in a log, write a script to monitor the log and restart the VPN when it goes down.  e.g. via something beginning with:

```
tail -F /var/log/syslog |
  awk '/your outage message/ { system "/path/to/vpn-restart-script" }'
```

or write a perl script using the [File::Tail](https://metacpan.org/release/File-Tail) module).   BTW, `File::Tail` is in the `libfile-tail-perl` package on Debian, so should be available on Raspbian too.

If you can't find an outage message in a log file and your VPN connection is started by a systemd service, you might be able to use `systemctl status <servicename>` to find out whether it's up or not.

In short, there are two parts to solving this:

1. Reliably detecting whether the VPN is up or not.  This might require a cron job, or a script to run in the background monitoring a log file.  It may require more than one test condition to detect the outage.
2. Restarting the VPN connection if it isn't.   This is probably as simple as running `systemctl restart servicename` if the VPN is started with a systemd service.  or `/etc/init.d/vpn-service` on SysV init.   (these names aren't exact, they're just placeholders for whatever your real service names are).

These parts can (and should) be solved independently of each other.